# Included objects in a Ria Services Query merging with previous requests

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm using Silverlight 4 with RIA Services, and I'm having the folowing problem:

I have a parent entity, lets call MyParent, and a child entity, called MyChild. The metadata class for the parent entity is as follows:

```
internal sealed class MyParentMetadata
{
    [Include]
    [Composition]
    public EntityCollection<MyChild> Childs { get; set; }
    (...)
```

when a make a query to the master entity, i include the child entity:

```
public IQueryable<MyParent> GetParentByID(int id)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.MyParent.Include("Childs").Where(x => x.ID == id);
}
```

In the client side, a use this code to make the request:

```
context.Load<MyParent> (context.GetParentByID(id), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, 
    lo => {
       var return = lo.Entities;
    });
```

The first time a make a request, it works fines. Lets say i made the request for parent Object 1 and get this result:

```
=> Parent 1
    => Child 1.1
    => Child 1.2
```

But when i make a second request for a diferent object, the childs from the first object appears to be merged into the second result. I get this:

```
=> Parent 2
    => Child 1.1
    => Child 2.1
    => Child 1.2
    => Child 2.2
```

How can i make sure that the 'Parent 2' object only have its own childs? The LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent parameter seems to be working only to the parent objects, but not for the childs.

Answer (score 0):

I have never needed `LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent` before. You are right it seems it does not work for Included Entities.

If I were you I prefer one of this way

- clearing context objects before load
- get a new instance of context (I know it does not seem well but solves the issue,we need this most cases for loading same type Entities but for different purposes).